# How to get Range result from Autofilter in Spreadsheetgear

Tags: autofilter, spreadsheetgear

I have the worksheet to keep BOM data. The columns as following:

| Bom header code | Semi-Item/Material | Q'ty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Semi-1 | 2 |
| A1 | Material-1 | 3 |
| A1 | Material-2 | 2.1 |
| Semi-1 | Semi-2 | 1 |
| Semi-2 | Semi-3 | 2 |
| Semi-3 | Material-3 | 5 |
| Semi-3 | Material-4 | 4 |

There are many BOM level and I want to return only A1, with list of materials.
1, Now I need to use AutoFilter many times and get the Range Result when I use AutoFilter.
2, Any other method to do this.

Thanks,

Duyet Le

I intend to convert to array and do that? Is it faster if I use AutoFilter?